# Using sys.exit(0) in an ArcMap Script Tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I'm using a ArcMap script tool to test if a facility is on a list. If it's not on the list, I want to print a statement and exit the script. The script works just fine as a standalone script but it errors out when I turn it into a script tool.

```
import arcpy, sys

FacID_raw = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

POT_ID_List = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]

for POT in POT_Search_List:
    POT_ID_List.append(str(POT.getValue("Facility_ID")))

if Fac_ID not in POT_ID_List:
    print Fac_ID + " not in List. Notify team lead."
    sys.exit(0)
```

The error I get is:

`Error Info:
      <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 0`

How do I exit out of a script tool when a condition isn't met?

Comment: sys.exit() is designed to terminate the process. Since Python is embedded in ArcGIS, this would terminate the ArcGIS Desktop session -- Probably not what your really want to do.  Please [Edit] the question to describe your intended outcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `exit()` after your print statement to exit the script.

```
if Fac_ID not in POT_ID_List:
    print(Fac_ID + " not in List. Notify team lead.")
    exit()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit

Comment: exit() also throws an error when the script gets imported into the script tool.

Comment: I was able to use exit() in ArcGIS 10.5 in both a script tool and python toolbox without error

Comment: Thanks, @Pdavis327. It must be something with my installation. `raise arcpy.ExecuteError` threw an error, too.

Answer (score 2):

Using functions allows you to use `return` to break out of them, and it's just good practice anyway.  Since your example is short you could just define a `main()` function to hold everything:

```
import arcpy, sys


def main():
    FacID_raw = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

    POT_ID_List = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]

    for POT in POT_Search_List:
        POT_ID_List.append(str(POT.getValue("Facility_ID")))

    if Fac_ID not in POT_ID_List:
        print Fac_ID + " not in List. Notify team lead."
        return

    # do more stuff


main()
```

Comment: This worked. I'm still peeved that the what's supposed to work isn't, but I'm glad for the work around. Thanks, @mikewatt.